# eclipse CDT:copying library paths from debug to release mode

Tags: c++, eclipse, configuration, build, eclipse-cdt

I have been developing a C++ app and running in debug mode, I have now set active build to release mode and have realized that I have to re-add all of the include paths and libraries (there are a lot of them!) is there any way to automatically do this/a bulk copy paste?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also select "all configurations" in the menu where you set your paths. The typical workflow for setting up a project is to first set "all configurations", do your stuff, and then selectively put in the Debug/Release specific things (like the NDEBUG symbol, or optimizer flags). No copying is required. Note that most good IDEs have this feature (including Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out (kinda). You can highlight all libs and copy them, then can just click on the box in the release dialogue and hit paste.